# Getting sum of $2 \pi$ periodic function

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions

I have a $2\pi$ periodic function which in the interval $[0,\pi]$ is $f(t) = \sin{\frac{t}{2}}$.

I have to find the sum for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. But do I know anything about $f(t)$ outside of $t \in [0,\pi]$?

I also have to find the effect of $f(t)$. Normally, I get the effect as $P(f) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t)|^2 \, \mathrm{d}t$, but how can I use this if I only know about the function in the interval $[0,\pi]$?

Maybe there is something I have misunderstood about periodic functions?

Comment: "I have to find the sum" What sum are you talking about, do you mean 'find the Fourier series'? When you state that $f$ is periodic then that defines $f$ outside of the inteval $[0,T]$ via $f(x+T) = f(x)$ so if you know $f$ on $[0,2\pi]$ then you know it on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I now see that I missed that it was only defined on $[0,\pi]$ + $2\pi$ periodic. That is a bit strange. Then you cannot say what the value of $f$ is on $[-\pi,0]$ solely from the information given.

Comment: What if I also have the information that the function is an equal function in the interval $[0,\pi]$? Does it make any difference?

Comment: If you mean that '$f$ is *even*' then that does make a difference as $f(-x) = f(x)$ would give you what you need.

Comment: Sorry. I did mean even :-) Thanks!